# How to insert a row with two columns modified

Tags: sql, sql-server

I didn't design this table; I just have to work with it. And modifying the design isn't really possible.

The table has ~50 columns. I want to copy a row, update two of the columns (a GUID and an int), and then insert it back into the table.

I can't seem to come up with how to do this **without listing all the columns**. Does someone have any techniques?

Comment: See the answer by Jonas as the best solution to your question

Comment: @Peterm, any way to do this without defining the columns?

Comment: Using a temp table means you only have to specify the columns being changed.  But it does mean multiple queries

Comment: Search this site by using statement: "Update + Select" ;) To update 2 columns you do not need to get entire row!

Comment: If typing is your primary concernt, in SQL Server Management studio you can drag the columns onto the query designer, meaning you don't need to type them all out. There is a visual demonstration in the article [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) by Aaron Bertrand. There are hacks for this such as selecting into a temp table (as described in the linked answer), but you will run into issues with computed columns and identity columns.

Comment: You might also try selecting from `syscolumns`, you can join on `sysobjects` and specify the table name, then syscolumns will give you the column names.  In this manner you could generate your sql statement in sql.

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into table_name (d1, d2,......)
select d1, d2, ...
from table_name
where unique_id = 'value'
```

Comment: OP defined his issue as: `I want to copy a row, update two of the columns  and then insert it back into the table.` So, INSERT + SELECT does not meet his needs ;(

Comment: he can UPDATE the table after copying

Comment: I don't get you, especially this: "after copying"...

Comment: UPDATE tickets SET tickets.ticket_number=(
   SELECT max_ticket FROM (
   SELECT (MAX(ticket_number)+1) AS max_ticket FROM tickets ) AS sub_table) 
WHERE ticket_id=12345;          @fuv answer